# Really slow wireless internet on 12.04 with HP dv6 6070ca

Tags: wireless, internet

I was recently running the previous version of Ubuntu through Wine, and everything was working great. I decided to upgrade to pangolin when I saw it came out. After upgrading the internet was very slow (the estimated time on the updates was something like 4 days).

I thought maybe this had something to do with the Wine installation, so I decided to finally do an actual dual boot. I partitioned my drive all nice and neat, but I made the mistake of connecting to the internet for the installation, and clicking the option to install updates and restricted extras.

This was in the morning, circa 6 am. Fast forward to the evening, the installation is frozen at around 75%. In frustration I gave the ol girl a hard shut-down, which effectively rendered my machine useless.

I used the thumb drive to reinstall Ubuntu, this time without connecting to the internet. Installed nice and easy, no problems, but the internet is still ridiculously slow. It took me about 20 minutes of frustration and hitting stop and reload repeatedly to even get this question page to open. This is important to me as now Windows won't even boot and I have to use ubuntu for the time being but I can't even bear to turn on my laptop due to the frustration that immediately ensues. Please help!

Oh, and I'm relatively new so if there are some terminal commands that spew out info you guys would find useful let me know what they are and I'll post back the information.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try this link
http://www.hitxp.com/articles/software/ubuntu-fix-slow-wireless-internet-connection-speed-upgrading-11-04-natty-narwhal/

please post back your findings so that we can help others

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.